# How to Capture Remote System network traffic?

Tags: linux, wireshark, spoofing

I have been using wire-shark to analyse the packets of socket programs, Now i want to see the traffic of other hosts traffic, as i found that i need to use monitor mode that is only supported in Linux platform, so i tried but i couldn't capture any packets that is transferred in my network, listing as 0 packets captured.

Scenario:

I'm having a network consisting of 50+ hosts (all are powered by windows Except mine), my IP address is 192.168.1.10, when i initiate a communication between any 192.168.1.xx it showing the captured traffic. 
But my requirement is to monitor the traffic of 192.168.1.21 b/w 192.168.1.22 from my host i,e. from 192.168.1.10.

1: is it possible to capture the traffic as i mentioned?

2: If it is possible then is wire-shark is right tool for it (or should i have to use      differnt one)?

3: if it is not possible, then why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connected to a switch which is "switching" traffic. It bases the traffic you see on your mac address. It will **NOT** send you traffic that is not destined to your mac address. If you want to monitor all the traffic you need to configure your switch to use a "port mirror" and plug your sniffer into that port.  There is no software that you can install on your machine that will circumvent the way network switching works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring

Answer (score 10):

Just adapt this a bit with your own filters and ips : (on local host)

```
ssh -l root <REMOTE HOST> tshark -w - not tcp port 22 | wireshark -k -i -
```

or using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
wireshark -k -i <(ssh -l root <REMOTE HOST> tshark -w - not tcp port 22)
```

You can use `tcpdump` instead of `tshark` if needed :

```
ssh -l root <REMOTE HOST> tcpdump -U -s0 -w - -i eth0 'port 22' |
     wireshark -k -i -
```

Comment: does this command to work do i need to install wireshark on those two hosts.

Comment: Wireshark on local host and tshark on the remote one

Comment: I don't have any possibilities to access those hosts to and install tshark or any other tools. is there any other ways.

Comment: tcpdump is maybe there, no ? If you need to see network traffic, you need at least one `pcap` capable tool.

Comment: i've installed the Linux to my host, but the other hosts are on windows, so is there better way to sniff traffic b/w those two hosts since windows is more vulnerable.

Comment: This is wonderful. I was in the old-school habit of capturing large blocks of packets and then feeding them to Wireshark. Or just using tcpdump on the collecting host to get real-time output. But being able to do it remote and real time is great!